# whether there exists a function with its power series is $\sum\limits_{m = 1}^N {\frac{{{x^m}}}{m}} $

Tags: calculus

For $\sum\limits_{m = 1}^N {\frac{{{x^m}}}{m}} $ with $x>1$, I want to find its diverging rate, I have tried a lot, such as I want to compute its $\int\limits_0^t {\frac{{{x^\tau }}}{\tau }} d\tau $. However, it is hard to me to obtain its integral.  Can anyone help me?

Comment: Try taking the derivative of this power series... do you recognize the result? Then integrate back, and compare the constant.

Comment: Is this really a finite series? Or should the $N$ be $\infty$?

Comment: $N$ be $\infty $